# Cardio with Plantar Fasciitis?

Tags: cardio

I got plantar fasciitis when I was training to become a spin and yoga instructor. I overworked my feet by doing hours of spin and yoga a day for 3 weeks. By the time I realized there was a problem, I couldn't walk, had to get cortisone shots, needed to go to physical therapy and see an orthopedist regularly. The reason that the fasciitis and tendinitis got so bad was because I have neuropathy in my feet so I don't feel pain when I'm supposed too. I do plan on retaking my training in a few months (although maybe this is a bad idea) and I would like to start spinning again in a month. Until then, what type of cardio can I do? I am trying to lose weight. I currently am doing Pilates regularly but need some cardio. I do not have access to a pool. Suggestions?

Comment: I encourage you to look into eccentric exercises for improving (and preventing relapse of) your plantar fasciitis.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start this answer by saying I'm somewhat biased (as in my user name, *rrirower*).  But, I'd be remiss  if I did not suggest using a [rower](http://www.concept2.com/) for your cardio.  In my opinion, a rower provides one of the best overall training experiences because it works many muscles concurrently.  And, since it's considered to be relatively low impact, you should be able to use it with minimal or no discomfort while you rehab your injury.

I would suggest you take a look at my answer to a similar question: [How can I train for a marathon with a damaged toe?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25489/how-can-i-train-for-a-marathon-with-a-damaged-toe/25493#25493) for further insight into why a rower may be a good fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rower is great tools for cardio, you should definitely try it out.

Besides that, stationary bikes sometimes works. Intensity is much lower, also usage depends on your condition. If you need higher intensitivity? Even push ups can be used as cardio exercise. For me kettlebell works fine, but my heels are OK.

Question is - what is target intensitivity. Can you try a bit of different exercises, and check one that do not hurt you? It can be that stationary bike, you have access to has great sit position, and that is 100% accurate? Maybe rower give right intensitivity? No one can tell that, but you.

What ever you choose. Rest is best treatment for your heels, so be wise, listen to your body, and train with out pain, at least with your heels.